# C++ - CORBA::LongSeq to long*

Tags: c++, pointers, corba

I'm new to C++ (I usually work on Java), and I'm trying to convert a ::CORBA::LongSeq object to a long * in C++, in order to perform operations on it afterwards.

So basically, what I tried is to do that :

```
long * Sample (const ::CORBA::LongSeq& lKeys) {
    long nbElts = lKeys.length();
    long * lCles = NULL;
    for(int iIndex = 0; iIndex < nbElts; iIndex++) {
        lCles[iIndex] = (long) lFCKey[iIndex];
    }
return lCles;
}
```

And what happens is that I can retrieve the length of *lKeys* (so it should be looking at the right location, as far as I can tell), but then I get an access violation exception when I enter inside the *for* loop.

> 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

I'm not sure of what I'm doing wrong though... Anyone has an idea ?

Comment: 1) Returning a pointer to a local variable is undefined behavior.  2) You pointer is NULL.  What did you expect to do with a NULL pointer?

Comment: looks like an invalid pointer

Comment: `I'm new to C++ (I usually work on Java),`  However you've misssed the basic fundamentals of pointer management.  Use a `std::vector<long>` instead of a `long *`.  Then all of this becomes one or two lines.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ok for the local variable, I moved it out of the method. But why would I get a reading exception rather than a writing exception here ?

Comment: It is platform dependent whether CORBA::Long == long, with the IDL to C++ language mapping you would have to use CORBA::Long in your code. With the IDL to C++11 language mapping it would be a int32_t, in the C++11 language mapping an IDL sequence is mapped to a std::vector, so you would get a std::vector<int32_t> with C++11

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Can't really use a std::vector as far as I can see, because all the treatment is done afterwards in C (there are things already set in place by... not me). And yeah, pretty hard to have the fundamentals when it's been 3 days of those languages actually :p

Comment: @PaulPicard You are accessing a NULL pointer.  Doesn't matter if it's read or write.  But the bottom line is that your code attempts to stuff in data into a pointer that points to ... we don't know. That's the issue.  Make it point to a buffer big enough to hold the data.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Okay, I think I got it. Will still take some time to get used to this, but oh well. Thanks for the explanation !

Comment: @PaulPicard `because all the treatment is done afterwards in C` C++ doesn't have scope resolution operators, but your function prototype has it.  So using intuition, it certainly doesn't look like this is being called from a C module.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Hmm, checked up again and yeah. My bad indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one solution, and you don't get into the mess with pointers:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<long> Sample (const ::CORBA::LongSeq& lKeys) 
{
    long nbElts = lKeys.length();
    std::vector<long> lCles(nbElts);
    for(int iIndex = 0; iIndex < nbElts; ++iIndex) 
        lCles[iIndex] = (long) lFCKey[iIndex];
    return lCles;
}
```

This is guaranteed to work correctly, if the number of elements is correct.

Since you say you know Java, then a `std::vector<long>` would be the equivalent to a few of the Java containers that store sequences of values.  For example, you can get the return value and call the vector's `data()` function to get you a `long *` that points to the vector's internal buffer.

But overall, get out of the pointer business (or try to limit their usage).

Edit:  The comment stated to use `CORBA::Long`.  So here it is:

```
std::vector<CORBA::Long> Sample (const ::CORBA::LongSeq& lKeys) 
{
    long nbElts = lKeys.length();
    std::vector<CORBA::Long> lCles(nbElts);
    for(int iIndex = 0; iIndex < nbElts; ++iIndex) 
        lCles[iIndex] = lFCKey[iIndex];
    return lCles;
}
```

Comment: It is not correct to assume CORBA::Long == long, it should be std::vector<CORBA::Long>

Comment: I would opt for dedicated conversion functions instead of carrying CORBA types along and into other layers.

Comment: The IDL to C++11 language mapping doesn't use specific CORBA types, it uses the C++11 types as defined in cstdint, that would remove the need of conversion of CORBA types to standard types

Answer (score 3):

The difference between Java and C++ is that you have to manage your memory yourself (in most cases).

The error you get is that you try to assign things to an uninitialized variable (`lCles`), and returning a local variable. The local variable `lCles` which is stored on the stack will be "destroyed" once you leave the method.

One suggestion of how to do this could be something like this:

```
long* lCles = new long[lKeys.length()];
for(int iIndex = 0; iIndex < nbElts; iIndex++) {
    lCles[iIndex] = (long) lFCKey[iIndex];
}
return lCles;
```

The important part in the method calling this code is to then release the memory held by this lCles by doing a

```
delete [] lCles; // or whatever the name of the variable is.
```

when done.

Like this:

```
long * l = Sample(lkeys);
// Do your stuff here
delete [] l;
```

(Using std::vector as suggested in another answer is actually preferred, since you don't have to do memory management by yourself.)

Answer (score 1):

There are two things wrong here.

1) You attempt to use lCles before you have initialised it:

```
long * lCles = NULL;
..
lCles[iIndex]
```

This causes the access violation inside the for loop.

2) You return a pointer, lCles which is only declared locally:

```
return lCles;
```

This means that it goes out of scope when the function exits, and it then becomes invalid.